# Blurryt text by transform: Rotate in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have a list  Hexagons In my web page like this

[image]

I had to use transform:rotate to have a correct text in it but in chrome text is Blurry ,in Mozilla it shows correctly

I searched a lot but there were no exact way.

I used this article to make these hexagons
http://www.queness.com/resources/html/css3-hexagon/index.html

and this is my html

```
 <div class="hex hex-3">
            <div class="inner">
                <h4>Energy</h4>
                <hr />
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
            <a href="#"></a>
            <div class="corner-1"></div>
            <div class="corner-2"></div>
        </div>
```

and some part of css which I used transform:rotate in it

```
 .hex {
transform: rotate(30deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
}

.inner {
transform: rotate(-30deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);
 }

 .hex .corner-1 {
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hex .corner-2 {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
 .hex .corner-1:before {
    transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-87px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.hex .corner-2:before {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-48px, -11px);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does the texts appear properly when no transformation is there?

Comment: @Roy  yes... I checked it and when I omit this two lines it shows correctly `.hex {    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);}
.inner {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);
}`

Comment: Why not just put the text on top of the transformed hexagon instead of inside it?

Comment: I need to do it if its the last chance because when I want to make it responsive it would have some problem and also  need to change the color by hover in jquery. but I will do it if there is no other way. really thank you for your care and help. @seahorsepip

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle/codepend/whatever? I can see if I can rewrite it without blurry text then.

Comment: @seahorsepip Thank you 100000 times for your care. here is the demo    https://jsfiddle.net/tn98fLsj/  appreciate you'r help

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh See my answer with a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been busy and it took me a while to find out but following css solves the issue:

```
.hex .corner-1,
.hex .corner-2,
.hex .corner-1:before,
.hex .corner-2:before {
    backface-visibility: inherit !important;
}
```

I was just having a similiar issue with a project that had a skewY tranform and found the bug while working on that, though in my project it was caused by a unnecessary rotateZ(0) transform.

Comment: woooow I don't know how to thank you. it works. . thank you 1000000 times, really appreciate you'r care and help..